# laravel query,redundant row will be inserted into to tabel invoice particulars.eg FROM table contains 6 rows,after exicuting TO table will 21 rows

Tags: php, laravel

```
$ar = $po_id;
$variableAry=explode(",",$ar);
foreach($variableAry as $var1) {

    $details11=DB::table('po_estimations')
        ->where('po_number',$var1)
        ->select('*')
        ->get();

    foreach($details11 as $details)
    {
        $inserts[] = ['invoice_id' => $key,'shade' => $details_>project_shade,'unit' => $details->unit,'In_range' => $details->project_range,'brand_name' => $details->brand_name,'particulars_name' => $details->po_number,];
        DB::table('invoice_particulars')->insert($inserts); //saves redundant data
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a little unclear of what you're trying to do.  Can you please include some description?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Like **Mihir Bhende** states your are constantly adding another element to your array and inserting that array on every iteration.

The following events are currently happening:

```
loop details
    add an array to the end of $inserts
    $inserts contains 1 element
    insert $inserts
    1 element has been inserted in the database

    next iteration

    add an array to the end of $inserts
    $inserts contains 2 elements (1 from the previous iteration)
    insert $inserts
    2 elements have been inserted in the database

    next iteration

    add an array to the end of $inserts
    $inserts contains 3 elements (2 from the previous iterations)
    insert $inserts
    3 elements have been inserted in the database

    next iteration

    ...
```

As you can see the `$inserts` array is growing bigger because all the previous additions to it remain.

One way to solve this is to put the `DB::table(...)->insert($inserts)` outside of the loop. If insist on only one query being executed you should implement the following:

```
foreach($details11 as $details)
{
    $inserts[] = ['invoice_id' => $key,'shade' => $details_>project_shade,'unit' => $details->unit,'In_range' => $details->project_range,'brand_name' => $details->brand_name,'particulars_name' => $details->po_number,];
}

DB::table('invoice_particulars')->insert($inserts); //saves redundant data
```

Otherwise **Mihir Bhende** answer will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$inserts[]` means to push into the array!
so each time it's executed, it will add a new item to the array.

what you want is:

```
foreach($details11 as $details)
{
    $inserts = ['invoice_id' => $key,'shade' => $details_>project_shade,'unit' => $details->unit,'In_range' => $details->project_range,'brand_name' => $details->brand_name,'particulars_name' => $details->po_number,];
    DB::table('invoice_particulars')->insert($inserts); //saves redundant data
}
```

so just remove the square brackets next to `$inserts[]` to become `$inserts`

Answer (score 0):

When you are using insert, you can either create one record or insert multiple :

**1. insert one record :**

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    'email' => 'test@something.com',
    'name' => 'stackoverflow'
]);
```

**2. insert multiple records :**

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    [
        'email' => 'test1@something.com',
        'name' => 'stackoverflow1'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'test2@something.com',
        'name' => 'stackoverflow2'
    ],
    [
        'email' => 'test3@something.com',
        'name' => 'stackoverflow3'
    ]
]);
```

Now in your case you are doing

`$insert[] = ['invoice_id' ....]`

which with every iteration in foreach is appending a new value and not assigning it. You can consider this similar to array_push behavior.

By doing this, 6 total values and looping in foreach each time 1 is added : 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 = 21 records inserted.

Update it to this :

```
foreach(explode(",",$ar) as $var1) {

    $details11=DB::table('po_estimations')->where('po_number',$var1)->get();

    foreach($details11 as $details)
    {
        DB::table('invoice_particulars')->insert([
            'invoice_id' => $key,
            'shade' => $details->project_shade,
            'unit' => $details->unit,
            'In_range' => $details->project_range,
            'brand_name' => $details->brand_name,
            'particulars_name' => $details->po_number
        ]);
    }
}
```